# drag and drop android overlapping images

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, overlap

I am working on this project where the user can customize their own pizza. How this works is the user can drag a topping to the plain pizza dough and once the topping has been dropped, the picture of the topping will then be displayed above the pizza dough. I've done this one but when I choose another topping to be dropped, the first topping was replaced by the current one. What I want to accomplish is to overlap the pictures just like the picture here. [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDjMD.jpg) I hope I can get answers. Thank you!

Comment: FrameLayout allows you to add view above another view.

Comment: So I can just drag and drop toppings multiple times and it will overlap? Hmm...how can I do it? Do I need multiple imageviews as well? Is there a certain code for that? I haven't tried using the frame layout though.

Comment: @DhirenParmar  
So I can just drag and drop toppings multiple times and it will overlap? Hmm...how can I do it? Do I need multiple imageviews as well? Is there a certain code for that? I haven't tried using the frame layout though

Comment: can you share your code for that?